# Angular Typeahead issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

[chick here to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAVD2.png)

When i am using Angular 1.6.0 typeahead is showing me this error. When i am using angular 1.5.8 every thing is working fine .

Please guide me how to fix this.

```js
$scope.queryAuto  = ["testdata1","testdata1", "testdata1" , "testdata1", "testdata1" ];

$scope.sharedData = [
query : ""
]
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" typeahead=" vr for vr in queryAuto | filter:$viewValue " ng-model="sharedData.query" placeholder="Enter Search Text" >
```

Comment: Without any code. How it is possible to fix ur error?

Comment: @Aravind FYR  i have posted how i am implementing the type-ahead ... If you are familiar with the issues or already faced this type of issue please help..

Comment: yes! Can you please elaborate you issue. are you available online?

Comment: yes sure how you want me to explain ....

Comment: Yes I am online ...Tell me how can you help @aravind

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get` returns an http response wrapped inside a promise, a promise has a function called `.then` that is invokes when the promise either resolves or rejects.
Angular comes with an implementation similar to the Q promise library, however along side `.then` they also provided accessory methods called `.success` and `.error`

These last 2 methods have been deprecated! you should use `.then` instead

so instead of doing something like

```
$http.get("path\to\api_url")
    .success(function(response) {
        return response.data; // success handler code
    }) 
    .error(function(response) {
        return response.status; // error handler code
    });
```

you should do

```
$http.get("path\to\api_url")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data; // success handler code
    }, function(response) {
        return response.status; // error handler code
    });
```

The `.then` function accepts 2 callbacks, a success handler and an rejection (error) handler (respectively), and only one of them will run.

**EDIT:**

According to the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), the angular team removed these methods in 1.6.0

> $http's deprecated custom callback methods - success() and error() - have been removed. You can use the standard then()/catch() promise methods instead, but note that the method signatures and return values are different.

So yeah, keep using 1.5.8 until ui-bootstrap will fix their code!

Comment: thanks for you response. I know the promises thing and i am already using that for my service response. According to my observation there are some issues/conflict ion while using Angular#1.6.0. I am currently using Angular#1.5.8 as a workaround for this.